# Reading an attribute of one HTML tag and writing it to an attribute of another HTML tag

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML `<img>` with an "alt" attribute. My `<img>` is wrapped in an `<a>`. The `<a>` has a "title" attribute. For example:

```
<a title="" href ="page.html"><img src="image.jpg" alt="text"></a>
```

I need to read the value of the "alt" attribute of the `<img>` and write it to the "title" attribute value of the `<a>`. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, e.g. DOM. What have you tried?

Comment: If you are rendering the whole thing via PHP, why can't you just render the alt attribute for both tags?

Comment: it would be lot easier/faster if you use jquery/javascript for this. If you use PHP, then also, its better to have id of each element of html to pick the correct title.

Comment: The HTML has been generated by Fireworks, it has an export as HTML option. It's for an HTML email. I'm doing some backend processing on this chunk of HTML to add the extra attributes I need.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by php

```
$url="http://example.com";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->getAttribute('alt');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As started by NullPointer,

```
  $url="http://example.com";

  $html = file_get_contents($url);

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTML($html);

  $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
     $parent = $tag->parentNode;
     if($parent->nodeName == 'a') {
         $parent->setAttribute('tittle', $tag->getAttribute('alt'));
     }
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent martinqt!! Thanks very much for this it's helped hugely!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JQUERY,

```
<script>
    var altValue = $('img').attr('alt');
    $('a').attr('title', altValue);
</script>
```

You have to use this when you need on onClick and if you have more img and a tags as follows

```
<script>
    function changeTitle(this) {
        var altValue = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
        $(this).find('a').attr('title', altValue);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Vinoth, while you solution would help on a webpage. In my case I'm doing some string processing on the backend. Thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. So once the output is rendered, you cannot change it anymore. (Unless you download the content with PHP and then output the changed data, but that seems only usefull if you cannot access the orignal source) If you are creating the output IN php you could use:

```
$alt = 'text';
echo '<a title="'.$alt.'" href ="page.html"><img src="image.jpg" alt="'.$alt.'"></a>';
```

If you already have the output, you could use jquery ( http://jquery.com/ )

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//perform after page is done
$(function() {

  //each image in an a tag
  $('a img').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var alt = $el.attr('alt');
    $el.parent('a').attr('title', alt);
  });
});
</script>
```

Update

If its pure PHP string modification, you could also use a regular expression to change it, instead of the dom manipulation:

```
$string = '<a title="" href ="page.html"><img src="image.jpg" alt="text"></a>';
$pattern = '/<a(.*?)title="(.*?)"(.*?)<img(.*?)alt="(.*?)"(.*?)<\/a>/i';
$replacement = '<a${1}title="$5"${3}<img${4}alt="${5}"${6}</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Hugo, a very concise solution! While it would help on a webpage. In my case I'm doing some string processing on the backend.

Comment: Ah ok, updated with some preg_replace, even though you have your awnser already.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php), I thought I'd offer a simple, plain-JavaScript, means of doing the same thing client-side:

```
function attributeToParent(tag, from, to, within) {
    if (!tag || !from || !to) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        within = within && within.nodeType == 1 ? within : document;
        var all = within.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        for (var i = 0, len = all.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (all[i].getAttribute(from) && all[i].parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
                all[i].parentNode.setAttribute(to, all[i].getAttribute(from));
            }
        }
    }
}

attributeToParent('img', 'alt', 'title');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ARGB2/1/).

This could be tidied up somewhat, but I think it's relatively clear as it is (albeit a little messier than I'd like).

References:

- [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute).
- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.tagName).

Comment: Thanks David! I need this to be part of a backend process though. I'm dealing with a chunk of HTML from a Fireworks "export as HTML". I need to run that HTML through a script to tidy it up a bit. Cheers for the Javascript solution.

Comment: You're welcome! I assumed it'd be most likely a server-side thing, but I saw the (somewhat needlessly) jQuery answers, and wanted to offer a plain-JavaScript alternative.